# What's the difference between direct assignment to `exports` and `Object.assign(exports, ...)`?

Tags: node.js, es6-modules, commonjs

This is Node.js 18.17.1. Here's my CommonJS module, `module1.cjs`:

```js
exports.a = 67
Object.assign(exports, { b: 68 })

console.log(exports)
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(exports, 'a'))
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(exports, 'b'))
```

And here's my ES module, `module2.mjs`:

```js
import * as module1 from './module1.cjs'
console.log(module1)
```

And the output:

```
{ a: 67, b: 68 }
{ value: 67, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
{ value: 68, writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true }
[Module: null prototype] { a: 67, default: { a: 67, b: 68 } }
```

As you can see, both exports `a` and `b` are present on the `exports` object, and they have identical descriptors aside from the value.

However, only `a`, which was created using direct assignment to `exports`, has actually survived as an export. `b`, which was created using `Object.assign` on `exports`, has not. If I were to do something like:

```js
import { a, b } from './module1.cjs
```

then my program would just fail because the export `b` doesn't exist.

Why is this?

I am aware that I can do `import module1 from './module1.cjs'; const { a, b } = module1` - however, that is only a workaround for this behaviour. What I'm hoping for is an explanation.

Comment: It appears the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65511127/when-can-a-commonjs-named-export-be-imported-by-an-es-module.  Named exports from a CommonJS modules are determined by static analysis of the code.  Simple assignments are captured.  Things assigned to exports by more indirect methods like `Object.assign()` are not.  See the above answer for more detail.  This is because named exports that you're going to use in an ESM module cannot be computed - they must be static.

Comment: I see, that actually makes some logical sense, thank you! You should add this as the actual answer to this question.